# WHERE statement returning out of bounds returns

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have this query that I'm trying to work with, and ultimately I'm trying to get it to return results as soon as it matches one of my status `WHERE` requirements....but that's not even my question. My question is that my query is returning a value that is TOTALLY out of bounds of my `WHERE` requirements, and it's just perplexing me as to why.

I have a table named `leads`. It has about ~30,000 rows in the table, but the specific dataset I want to be targeting is here:

```
+---------+--------+---------+
| lead_id | status | owner   |
+---------+--------+---------+
|    3653 |     18 | 6585993 |
|    3984 |      3 | 6585993 |
|    4100 |     18 | 6585993 |
|    8916 |     21 | 6585993 |
|   20329 |      1 | 6585993 |
+---------+--------+---------+
```

Lead ID is the primary key, it's `int(11)` and `AUTO_INCREMENT`ing, `status` is a `FOREIGN KEY`, and `owner` is a `FOREIGN KEY` as well.

Here is the query I'm working with:

```
SELECT lead_id, status, owner FROM leads
    WHERE owner = 6585993 AND (`status` = 1) OR (`status` = 21) OR (`status` = 3)
    LIMIT 1;
```

My ultimate goal with this query is I want to have it cascade through my last three `WHERE` requirements (ie, first check the `owner` requirement, then - if there exists no lead with a `status` of "1", then check for leads with a `status` of "21" and if no lead exists with a `status` of "1" or "21", then check for leads with a `status` of "3", and if no leads exist with any of those three statuses who also have the correct `owner` requirement, return none.

With how the query is written above, it returns the what I expect:

```
+---------+--------+---------+
| lead_id | status | owner   |
+---------+--------+---------+
|   20329 |      1 | 6585993 |
+---------+--------+---------+
```

Here's the problem...when I change my `status` cascade to look like this (change it so that the status of "21" is to be selected first):

```
SELECT lead_id, status, owner FROM leads WHERE owner = 6585993 AND (`status` = 21) OR (`status` = 1) OR (`status` = 3) LIMIT 1;
```

It returns this:

```
+---------+--------+---------+
| lead_id | status | owner   |
+---------+--------+---------+
|    9435 |      1 | 1083618 |
+---------+--------+---------+
```

And herein lies my ultimate question...

**Why does the above query return a response with a completely wrong `owner`?**

Comment: Have you tried to set an order? (ORDER CASE in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost:

Change your where clause and put all OR's inside a single parenthesis.

```
SELECT 
    lead_id, status, owner 
FROM 
    leads 
WHERE 
    owner = 6585993 
    AND ((`status` = 1) OR (`status` = 21) OR (`status` = 3))
ORDER BY
    CASE `status` 
        WHEN 1 THEN 0 
        WHEN 21 THEN 1
        WHEN 3 THEN 2
    END
LIMIT 1
;
```

Then, if you prefer and order, set and ORDER BY clause using a case to assign the new values, 1 = First (0), 21 = Second (1) and 3 = Last (2).

> ```
> lead_id | status |   owner
> ------: | -----: | ------:
>   20329 |      1 | 6585993
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b1ed303a7311ad0e4bb4e9aa2c842a23)*

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!!! I still don't know why it was matching to a completely different owner...but I don't really care about that, now that I found the answer I needed.

Comment: There is no expected order until you set up an ORDER.

Comment: Even shorter:  `status IN (1, 21, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibility and you have to **set an order** when you try to LIMIT

So add to the both query below an `ORDER BY`, to get the right id

```
SELECT 
    lead_id, status, owner 
FROM leads 
WHERE owner = 6585993 
    AND ((`status` = 1) OR (`status` = 21) OR (`status` = 3)) 
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(status,1,21,3)
LIMIT 1;
```

Or you use

```
SELECT 
    lead_id, status, owner 
FROM leads 
WHERE owner = 6585993 
    AND `status` IN ( 1, 21, 3) 
ORDER BY FIELD(status,1,21,3)
LIMIT 1;
```